# log's different values on changing variable name

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

HTML

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="name">
    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="email">
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

JS

```js
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
var email = document.getElementById("email");
var name = document.getElementById("name");
console.log(name);
console.log(email);
```

console output:

```
[object HTMLInputElement]
<input type="email" id="email" placeholder="email">
```

But if I just change the variable name of `document.getElementById("name")` from `name` to `x` the console output changes

new JS

```js
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
var email = document.getElementById("email");
var x = document.getElementById("name");
console.log(x);
console.log(email);
```

console output

```
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="name">
<input type="email" id="email" placeholder="email">
```

Can someone explain why and what is the problem with the variable name `name`?

Comment: Check if there any other "x" variable in the code

Comment: @Govi-Boy That is all the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is going on over here is that when you are declaring `name` var, you are actally re-assigning `name` var in the global scope. And then the input element is getting  converted to string. Which is because when you run this script in global scope, you are basically asking for window.name to be changed.

As per the MDN Docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name), window.name will convert all values to their string representations by using the `toString` method.

Now, to avoid this issue, there are several ways, one of which is to not write your script in global scope and that is what I will recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Use `const` or `let` instead of `var`, it will fix your issue.

Because of the scope of `var` is conflicting with `window.name` somehow.